# How to mutate row-wise and replace first 'n' values with 0

Tags: r, dplyr

I'm trying to build a measurement tracker form.  I'd like to populate 0 into the "Measurement" columns for each row, based on the Quantity value for that row.  (For Quantity = 2, first 2 measurements = 0, the rest of the row = NA). (For Quantity = 4, all measurements = 0).

I'm wondering how to mutate these rows and replace with the proper number of 0s in the correctly indexed positions, like so:

```
 Feature Tool MIN MAX Quantity Measurement_1 Measurement_2 Measurement_3 Measurement_4
1       a    m 0.5 1.0        2             0             0            NA            NA
2       b    n 0.4 1.2        4             0             0             0             0
```

The sample code to generate the dataframe is here:

```
#sample data
A1 <- data.frame(Feature = c("a","b"), Tool = c("m","n"), MIN = c(0.5,0.4), MAX = c(1.0,1.2), Quantity = c(2,4))  

# Create empty data frame of NA
df <- data.frame(matrix(NA,    
                          nrow = 1,
                          ncol = max(A1$Quantity)))

#create list of sequential measurements based on maximum quantity of measurements
M <- c(sprintf("Measurement_%01d", seq(1,max(A1$Quantity)))) 

#set column names to these measurements
colnames(df) <- M  

#combine sample data with measurements
new_dat <- cbind(A1, df)
```

My first attempts to accomplish this are something like this:

```
new_dat %>% rowwise() %>% mutate(new_dat[,6:new_dat$Quantity] <- 0)
```

But it's clear I'm missing something here.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A vectorized approach in `base R` would be using `row/column` indexing.  Create a matrix with row index replicated and the column index for each rows, and then do the assignment

```
j1 <- grep("Measurement", names(new_dat))
new_dat[cbind(rep(seq_len(nrow(new_dat)), new_dat$Quantity),
         j1[sequence(new_dat$Quantity)])] <- 0
```

-output

```
> new_dat
  Feature Tool MIN MAX Quantity Measurement_1 Measurement_2 Measurement_3 Measurement_4
1       a    m 0.5 1.0        2             0             0            NA            NA
2       b    n 0.4 1.2        4             0             0             0             0
```

---

Or with `dplyr`, we could do

```
library(dplyr)
new_dat %>% 
  mutate(across(starts_with("Measurement"),
    ~ replace(.x, readr::parse_number(cur_column()) <= Quantity, 0)))
```

-output

```
  Feature Tool MIN MAX Quantity Measurement_1 Measurement_2 Measurement_3 Measurement_4
1       a    m 0.5 1.0        2             0             0            NA            NA
2       b    n 0.4 1.2        4             0             0             0             0
```

Comment: akrun, you are the man!  Thank you for the help.  Do you have any recommendations for tutorials or books to improve my working knowledge of 'dplyr'?  Some of these more complicated use cases are difficult for me.

Comment: @raga_muffin i guess you can look at the [vignettes](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/dplyr/vignettes/dplyr.html) of dplyr and other related packages of tidyverse.  It would be more uptodate